# Can I combine MVC2 with MVC3 in the same application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC2 application and I need to add code from another application that is MVC3-based.

What happens if I just change references in my program from MVC2 to MVC3? Will it work? Will newly added MVC3-based code likely work? What are typical problems I should expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot combine the 2 versions in the same ASP.NET application. On the other hand you could upgrade your ASP.NET MVC 2 application to ASP.NET MVC 3. There are some [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034229) you could expect though. You could do this either [manually](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) or by using an [upgrade tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx).

Comment: What will likely malfunction first? What do I do - choose between complete forward porting and partial back porting?

Comment: @sharptooth, the answer to this question will greatly depend on what is your application doing and what functionality it uses. There are some breaking changes but I would go for a full upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 3. You could keep the WebForms view engine if you don't have time to port all the views to Razor.

Answer (score 2):

While the two cannot coexist in the same assembly, you should have no issue upgrading from MVC2 to MVC3.

There are some [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034229) between MVC2 and MVC3, but in all likelihood you aren't going to hit into them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade since you can't combine the both.

There is an upgrade tool available: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx

The link also shows a detailed description how an upgrade should be done.

Comment: There are breaking changes. http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034229